# Can someone explain using SSID + inform vs interface wlan#?

Tags: raspbian, wifi, raspbian-stretch

I'm here to learn, so advice is appreciated.

Since moving over the Stretch, by selecting wifi from the menubar it seemed to populate the `tail` of my `/etc/dhcpdc.conf` with:

`SSID <my AP>
inform 10.0.1.10
static routers=10.0.1.1
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8`

My RPi didn't seem to like it.  It connected, but there were other issues.  When I replaced that format with the following, from a Jesse Pi, it behaved as I expected.

`interface wlan0
static ip_address=10.0.1.10/24
static routers=10.0.1.1
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`

Can someone explain the differences of the two, or point me to a tutorial, so a newbie like me can better understand Pi networking?

Comment: `man dhcpcd.conf` should explain the options; `inform` is in this: https://www.daemon-systems.org/man/dhcpcd.conf.5.html Prefer the system man page if they conflict.

Comment: BTW: AFAIK SSID/inform and interface/static are not linked pairs. SSID/static, etc is also possible. I have used interface/inform and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is what `man dhcpcd.conf` tells

> `inform` [...] sends a DHCP INFORM instead of DISCOVER/REQUEST.  This
>   does not get a lease as such, just notifies the DHCP server of the
>   address in use.  You should also include the optional cidr network
>   number[...]
>
> If you set `static ip_address` then dhcpcd will not attempt to obtain
>   a lease and just use the value for the address with an infinite lease
>   time. [...]
>
> **For IPv4, you should use the `inform` ipaddress option instead of setting a static address.**